# sqlite php getting unrecognized token: ":" error while inserting and parameterized query

Tags: php, sqlite

I am working with sqlite for the first time.

Preparing a query string like

```
$articleInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Articles VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", ($i, $title, $content, $date, 93,);
```

It returns "Parse error". I also tried without passing parametrized query like

```
$articleInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Articles VALUES ($i, $title, $content, $date, 93)";
```

ANd getting `"Unable to prepare statement: 1, unrecognized token: ":" "`

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any function to do that? If so, show us.

Comment: $query = $dbObject->prepare($articleInsertQuery);
    $query->execute();

Comment: Hey @arnold, From which class?

Comment: class AppDBClass extends SQLite3{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('../Server/db/sqlite3_database.db');
    }
} And $dbObject = new AppDBClass();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@arnoldIf you are using PDO for that.

The way to [prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and execute your query would be as follows.

```
$dbObject = new PDO('sqlite:sqlitedb');// NEW LINE
$articleInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Articles VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$query = $dbObject->prepare($articleInsertQuery);
$query->execute(array($i, $title, $content, $date, 93));
```

**EDIT:**

See [sqlite3 prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php).

```
$articleInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Articles VALUES (:i, :title, :content, :date, :int)";
$query = $dbObject->prepare($articleInsertQuery);
$query->bindValue(':i', $i, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
$query->bindValue(':title', $title, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$query->bindValue(':content', $content, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$query->bindValue(':date', $date, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$query->bindValue(':int', 93, SQLITE3_INTEGER);    

$result = $query->execute();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For first solution it returns PHP Warning:  SQLite3Stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @arnold... Try the lower one.

Comment: It will be like  $query->execute(); Right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry... the copy/paste issue.

Comment: And I am getting this SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: constraint failed

Comment: Is date a date-type in the table scheme?

Comment: On the `date` line change _SQLITE3_TEXT_ to _SQLITE3_BLOB_.

Comment: Also, try to use the first solution with the new line I just added. Using PDO would be a better option.

Comment: Changed it getting same SQLite3Stmt::execute(): Unable to execute statement: constraint failed